# Cant get ChartJS xAxes to display as minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

I have a workout generator which displays times as TIME in MySQL DB. These workouts need to include the possibility of being an hour long but most are under an hour e.g 23 mins 10 seconds. Using chart.js I need to be able to display time in minutes and seconds on my xAxes

## My Workout Chart

```
    <canvas id="chart" style="width: 100%; height: 60vh; background: white; border: 1px solid #555652; margin-top: 10px;"></canvas>

    <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,14,16,17,18,19,],
            datasets:
                    [{
                            label: 'Time Performed',
                            data: [<?php echo $data1; ?>],
                            backgroundColor: 'orange',
                            borderColour: 'rgba(255,99,132)',
                            fill: false,
                            borderwidth: 1
                    },
                            {
                            label: 'RPE',
                            data: [<?php echo $data2; ?>],
                            backgroundColor: 'green',
                            borderColour: 'rgba(255,99,132)',
                            fill: false,
                            borderwidth: 1 
                }]

        },

        options: {
        scales: {scales:{yAxes: [{beginAtZero: true}], xAxes: [{autoskip: true, maxTicketsLimit: 20}]}},
        tooltips:{mode: 'index'},
        legend:{display: true, position: 'top', labels: {fontColour: 'rgb(255,255,255)', fontSize: 16}}
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please explain your question and not only what you did.

Comment: my question is how do I display time in minutes and seconds on my xAxes